# Show 25 results by default in a jQuery table

Tags: jquery, datatables

During testing, I have to show 25 results instead of 10 in a jQuery table. Do you have any clue how to change this property in a select tag, please? Thanks in advance.

Learning something new about jQuery tables results

Example table header

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquerry+table+paging+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What framework? DataTables?

Comment: Hi again @mplungjan! Spring Framework and data from Oracle DB, mainly.

Comment: But what is the jQuery table? And please [edit] and update your question with relevant information

Comment: Post CODE, not just pictures (of code). If you want help, please do not ignore my requests in the first comment I made. Did you even [click on the link I gave you](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+table+paging+site%3Astackoverflow.com)? What you want is called paging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this snippet when initializing jQuery DataTables in your code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 25
        });
      });
```

This snippet sets the default number of entries to display to 25 per page.

Comment: That's the way I asked! Many thanks, @AhmedAliRajput, bless you! ;)

Comment: You're most welcome